# Cannot run docker-compose push on clickhouse docker image: resource denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am attempting to get a clickhouse cluster running in docker swarm on my 3-node nuc cluster, secifically running clickhouse on two of the nodes. My setup is as follows:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:21:35 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

I am leveraging documentation from here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

Keeping things simple and from a previous post, my steps are:

```
1. create registry: docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000 registry:2

2. clone https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/tree/master/docker/server

3. cd into the server folder

4. run docker-compose up -d

5. it seems to run through, but some things are not compiling properly:

        Name                      Command                State                       Ports                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clickhouse_builder_1   /bin/bash /build.sh              Exit 1                                                
clickhouse_client_1    /usr/bin/clickhouse-client ...   Exit 210                                              
clickhouse_server_1    /entrypoint.sh                   Up         0.0.0.0:8123->8123/tcp, 9000/tcp, 9009/tcp
```

When I try docker-compose push I get:

```
ushing builder (yandex/clickhouse-builder:latest)...
The push refers to repository [docker.io/yandex/clickhouse-builder]
25191c01f764: Preparing
a45a4a0fdaa6: Preparing
a4d49d090007: Preparing
a7333d91116d: Preparing
122be11ab4a2: Preparing
7beb13bce073: Waiting
f7eae43028b3: Waiting
6cebf3abed5f: Waiting
ERROR: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

**UPDATE:**

With no need to run docker-compose push as David suggested, I went ahead and pulled https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker-compose.yml and placed it in the server directory of the repo I cloned and ran (had to change version to "3"):

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml medusa
```

**Update**

Removed builder and client from the .yml file since for now what I am looking to do is create server to communicate with. Client will be built separately. Runs good now it seems. 
checked the services:

```
docker stack services medusa

ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                              PORTS
cu3bf94zbuxa        medusa_client       replicated          0/1                 yandex/clickhouse-client:latest    
p3bryrrl8wro        medusa_server       replicated          1/1                 yandex/clickhouse-server:latest    *:8123->8123/tcp
vluijvflilkv        medusa_builder      replicated          0/1                 yandex/clickhouse-builder:latest
```

Am I correct in assuming that the client and builder are not running? I run the visualizer as an aid:

https://github.com/dockersamples/docker-swarm-visualizer

and I am seeing services appear and reappear:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `docker-compose push` pushes a built _image_ to some registry, by default Docker Hub.  You don't need to do it just to run a container stack, and you can't do it for images owned by someone else on Docker Hub.

Comment: I see, fundamental misunderstanding then. But I see now in the documentation the push is to the hub. I noticed that there is no docker-compose.yml in that repo. Would I have to build my own to run: docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml? Before I was attempting to run the offical .yml file https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/docker-compose.yml